# Cannot read property of undefined angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have issue with Angular factory, I've tried many ways, but it's same..

This is error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSchedule' of undefined
        at new <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:4767/js/ctrls/main.js:3:19)
        at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:35:36)
        at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:35:165)
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:67:419
        at link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js:7:248)
        at N (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:54:372)
        at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:47:256)
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:46:377
        at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:48:217
        at F (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:52:28) <ng-view class="app-content ng-scope" ng-hide="loading">
```

I have constructed main app this way:

```
'use strict';

// Declare chat level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('BenShowsApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource',
    'mobile-angular-ui',
    'BenShowsApp.filters',
    'BenShowsApp.services',
    'BenShowsApp.directives',
    'BenShowsApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/schedule', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            });
}]);

//Initialize individual modules
var services = angular.module('BenShowsApp.services', []);
var factories = angular.module('BenShowsApp.factories', []);
var controllers = angular.module('BenShowsApp.controllers', []);
var filters = angular.module('BenShowsApp.filters', []);
var directives = angular.module('BenShowsApp.directives', []);
```

and tried use this factory/service

```
services.factory('tvRage', function($http) {
        var tvRage = {};
        tvRage.getSchedule = function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/fullschedule.php',
                params: {
                    country: 'US',
                    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        };
    return tvRage;
});
```

with this controller

```
controllers.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http','tvRage',
    function ($scope, $http, tvRage) {
            tvRage.getSchedule().success(function(data){
                var parser = new X2JS();
                var x2js = parser.xml_str2json(data);
                $scope.request = x2js;
            }).error(function(){
                alert('nouuu');
            });
    }
]);
```

**$http** works when it's all in controller, but from functional side that request should be in factory I think.

Comment: These are in the same file? If not, you probly forgot to include the file in the index.html

Comment: @Fals no they aren't, but everything is linked.

Comment: promisses have then not success method, thats the issue!

Answer (score 3):

You are returning `$q` promise from the factory. It does not have the methods `success` and `error` they are special functions added by `$http` in the returned httpPromise (which is just an extension of QPromise).

You can either change your factory to return httpPromise by removing the `then` chaining:

```
  return $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/fullschedule.php',
            params: {
                country: 'US',
                key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
        });
```

Or chain it in your controller with standard q promise functions `then`/ `catch`.

```
controllers.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http','tvRage',
    function ($scope, $http, tvRage) {
            tvRage.getSchedule().then(function(data){
                var parser = new X2JS();
                var x2js = parser.xml_str2json(data);
                $scope.request = x2js;
            }).catch(function(){
                alert('nouuu');
            });
    }
]);
```

But with the specific error you are getting it looks like possibly in your original code your DI list does not match argument list. Re-verify by logging what is `tvRage` and other arguments injected in the controller. This could easily happen because of argument mismatch in the original code. Ex:-

```
 .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','tvRage', function ($scope, $http, tvRage){
    //Now tvRage will be undefined and $http will be tvRage.
```

**Working Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'tvRage',
  function($scope, $http, tvRage) {

    tvRage.getSchedule().success(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }).error(function() {
      alert('nouuu');
    });
  }
]).factory('tvRage', function($http) {
  var tvRage = {};
  tvRage.getSchedule = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/fullschedule.php',
      params: {
        country: 'US',
        key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
    });
  };
  return tvRage;
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
</div>
```

Comment: I was wondering that too, but... that doesn't explain the error message does it? it was trying to access `getSchedule` of undefined, which would mean `tvRage` was undefined.

Comment: huff you are right.. i did not look at the error message closely.  I am assuming issue could be `.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','tvRage', function ($scope,$http, tvRage){`

Comment: thanks for advice, but not working. Only one change is error to "undefined is not a function"

Comment: @Jayme Can't help much with your displayed code, we can only assume and try to help with the code in the question. See the demo in my answer, it should just work. Please replicate the issue with a demo link. How does the controller DI and argument look like in your original code.

Comment: All upside is original code. app, controller and factory are in different files. And I've tried put factory beside controller and it works! It must be evil magic or something.. :-D Out of record - I'm newbie with Angular

Comment: @Jayme Did you get any luck with this yet?